# aiohttp - running client example "RuntimeError: SSL is not supported"

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm just trying to go through the aiohttp examples but I get the error with the first one:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Running this gets me this:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\asyncio\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 887, in _get_ssl_context
>       raise RuntimeError('SSL is not supported.')
>   RuntimeError: SSL is not supported.

- Python version: 3.7.3
- aiohttp version: 3.5.4

I searched for the problem replicating but I couldn't find anything... which leads me to think there's something wrong with my setup. I'm running this on Windows 8.1 using Anaconda2 env.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aiohttp imports `ssl` [as follows](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py#L59):

```
try:
    import ssl
    SSLContext = ssl.SSLContext
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    ssl = None  # type: ignore
    SSLContext = object # type: ignore
```

If then it is still `None`, it rises error specified in your post. Thus, first of all try to `import ssl` manually. It should look somewhat like that:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl
<module 'ssl' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py'>
```

If it does not, then check/reinstall your python setup.

Comment: Your solution is correct. I don't have the ssl installed. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it was related to using Anaconda. I installed python3.7, then virtualenv and created a virtual enviroment and everything works fine now