# Trying to make Discord bot, receive following error: RuntimeError: SSL is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make my first Discord bot following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/), but I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: SSL is not supported.
```

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

This code is directly copied and pasted from the tutorial because I wanted to make sure I didn't have a typo that was causing the error. I'm guessing the error is not in that code itself, but in the way something is set up on my computer, but I have no idea how SSL works and where to even start trying to fix it. I tried using the block of code from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629636/aiohttp-running-client-example-runtimeerror-ssl-is-not-supported) where someone got the same error but in a different context, but that did not work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the configuration with pythonw.exe not python.exe. So just edit the configuration and change the python interpreter to pythonw.exe.